# `column` from `util-linux` and not from `bsdmainutils`

Tags: linux-mint, columns, util-linux

`column` is available in packages `util-linux` and `bsdmainutils`. Both these packages are installed in Linux Mint 20.2

```
$ type column
column is /usr/bin/column
column is /bin/column
```

Both these column are pointing to the bsd column tool. How can I access the tool from `util-linux`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux Mint 20.2, `util-linux` doesn’t provide `column`; the version shipped in Mint is 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1, but the package only started providing `column` [in version 2.35.2-3 of the package](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1154475/accepted-util-linux-2352-3-source-amd64-all-into-unstable-unstable/).

You can verify which packages provide a given binary using `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file search bin/column
autogen: /usr/bin/columns                 
bsdmainutils: /usr/bin/column
xymon: /usr/lib/xymon/cgi-bin/columndoc.sh
```

`column` changed packages during a transition from `bsdmainutils` to `util-linux`; this transition hasn’t reached Mint yet. The old `bsdmainutils` tools are now part of a new `bsdextrautils` package, which is built from `util-linux`. This will only be available in Linux Mint once a release is made based on Ubuntu 21.04 or later.

If you really want the `util-linux` version of `column`, you’ll have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two executables with the same name, and both are in the PATH - just define a full path: `/usr/bin/column`

Or make an alias to it:
`alias clmn='/usr/bin/column'`
And use that alias in the future work. Do not forget to add alias definition to your .profile or .bashrc.

Or make a bin folder in your home directory, put there a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/column $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
```

Call that script "column", and make sure that the $HOME/bin is the first in the path.

Or just uninstall the tools which you do not need.

Comment: In this instance, both binaries are the same: `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.