# How does awk print the columns in right-justify?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have INPUT data like this:

```
V 0.886 3.768 -2.882
C -0.082 3.768 -3.850
M -0.900 3.769 4.669
F -0.001 3.768 -3.769
```

I expect OUTPUT formatting like this:

```
V    0.886  3.768    -2.882
C   -0.082  3.768    -3.850
M   -0.900  3.769     4.669
F   -0.001  3.768    -3.769
```

I use this command: `awk -v '{print $1, "\t", $2, "\t", $3, "\t", $4}'`However, it prints out the rows, not in the queue.

```
V  0.886  3.768  -2.882
C  -0.082 3.768  -3.850
M  -0.900 3.769  4.669
F  -0.001 3.768  -3.769
```

The `column -t` command does not show me the needed results either. It shows something like:

```
V    0.886  3.768     -2.882
C    -0.082  3.768    -3.850
M    -0.900  3.769    4.669
F    -0.001  3.768    -3.769
```

Can you please let me know how to correct it?

Comment: preferred answer on SO [Using awk to align columns in text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14098878/4023950)

Comment: use [column -R](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html). Unfortunately if you're using Ubuntu then you'll need to install `column` from `util-linux` because the default one is from the terrible `bsdmainutils`. See [How can I install the util linux version of the column command in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1098248/253474), [`column` from `util-linux` and not from `bsdmainutils`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685196/44425)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you want to print your data as tab-delimited columns and that each numerical column should have the `printf` format `%6.3f`, i.e. a 6 characters wide floating point number with 3 decimal places (right-justified by default).

```bash
$ awk '{ printf "%s\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' file
V        0.886   3.768  -2.882
C       -0.082   3.768  -3.850
M       -0.900   3.769   4.669
F       -0.001   3.768  -3.769
```

This uses `printf` with the format string `%s\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n` to print each set of four fields.  The first field is printed as a string (`%s`), while the others are formatted as described above.  Between each field, a tab character (`\t`) is outputted, and there will be a newline (`\n`) at the end.

Note that this produces tab-delimited data with fields padded with space characters.  Below, the tabs are represented by `^I` in the output of `cat -t`:

```bash
$ awk '{ printf "%s\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' file | cat -t
V^I 0.886^I 3.768^I-2.882
C^I-0.082^I 3.768^I-3.850
M^I-0.900^I 3.769^I 4.669
F^I-0.001^I 3.768^I-3.769
```